# Shell variable doesn't change with pipe-while-read combination

Tags: command-line, bash

Consider case 1:

```
$ COUNT=0 ; while [ $COUNT -ne 3  ]; do echo $COUNT; COUNT=$(expr $COUNT + 1 );done
0
1
2
$ echo $COUNT
3
```

By the end of the loop `COUNT` variable is 3, as expected

Consider case 2:

```
$ COUNT=1; find . -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' FILE; do echo "$FILE"; expr $COUNT + 1; COUNT=$(expr $COUNT + 1 )  ;done 
.
2
./file name
3
./file
4
./a
b
5
$ echo $COUNT
1
```

As you can see, in this case COUNT remained the same. Why ?  It can be seen that it's changing inside the while loop, but not once it's out of the loop.

What exactly I am missing here ?

Comment: This looks like useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16854326/1391444

Comment: @JacobVlijm that's pretty much a duplicate of my question . . . except we cannot close-as-dupe across sites :) Thanks

Comment: No, I wasn't intending to have it closed. I was pretty sure however that one of the `bash` -persons would be much more into it than I am (in `bash`), to point out what exactly happens *and* to propose an elegant solution in this case :).... And I see you did it :)

Comment: Hehe, well maybe I should start posting python questions so that you can answer those :)  Well frankly, I expected more enthusiasm from bash folks here as well . . . This was utterly confusing me for half the evening before i decided to post a question. But in any case  I just found this : http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024 . . .There's pretty much several workarounds.  Case closed

Comment: That's quite a nice story!

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy you're lucky you spent only half the evening tracking down this boondoggle! only problem for me is, I'm piping out to `dialog` for a long-running loop, but need to track several variables that are modified in the loop 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your first case, all commands executed in the same shell. The content of `COUNT` is changed.

In your second case a subshell is started with piping `|`, and changes in the subshell have no effect in the current shell. But he subshell knows the variable `COUNT` and the first output is `2`.

Comment: Makes sense.  How does one make it work as expected though ?

Comment: OK, got it. I have to group the while together : `COUNT=0; find . -print0 | ( while IFS= read -r -d '' FILE; do echo "$FILE"; COUNT=$((COUNT+1));done ; echo $COUNT )`

Comment: Maybe you could edit it into the answer if @Serg agrees. Always nice to have the explanation & solution together in the answer.

Comment: Sure, please use that ! I am always supporting anything that can help other non-pro users like myself :)

Comment: @Serg That won't work, because the `while` loop still runs in a forked shell; in this case you can use a process substitution to invert the commands so that `find` runs in the forked shell and the `while` loop runs in the current shell: `COUNT=0; while IFS= read -r -d '' FILE; do echo "$FILE"; COUNT=$((COUNT+1));done <<(find . -print0); echo $COUNT`

Comment: @kos or a named pipe :D I've been reading up on all the various workarounds to this this night. Fun stuff !

Comment: @Serg: Named pipes are a PITA because you have to get rid of them when you're done.